# scrape specific td in row in table

Tags: python-3.x

I am scrapping a website for certain data. 
My code works fine up to a point. It finds the specific tables and rows I want and then selects the cells and puts them in a dict. My problem is selecting the last cell in a row.

```python
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import pandas as pd

theurl = "http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/IATA_Codes/airport_code_list.htm"
thepage = urllib
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup=BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
air=[]
init_data = open('/Users/paribaker/Desktop/air.txt', 'a')
count = 0
while count <73:
    title = soup.find_all('table',{'class':'tb86'})[(count)]
    rows = title.findAll('tr')[1:]
    data = {
        'city' : [],
        'country' : [],
        'code' :[]

        }
    for row in rows:
        col1 = row.find_all('td')[0]
        col2 = row.find_all('td')[1]
        col3 = row.find_all('td')[2]
        print (col1.text)
        print(col2.text)
        print(col3.text)
        #col3 = row.find_all('td')[1]
        #data['city'].append( col1.get_text())
        #data['country'].append( col2)
        #data['code'].append( col3)
        #dogData = pd.DataFrame(data)
        #dogData.to_csv("dog.csv")
    count += 3
```

I get an error saying that td[2] is not within the range. When I look at the selector of the td it says it is the 3rd one so I would use [2]. 
Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

A few debugging statements reveal there are only two `<td>` cells in some rows. In fact, this is true for the very first `row` in `rows`:

```
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    print("Row {}:\n".format(i))
    for j, td in enumerate(row.find_all('td')):
        print(" Cell {}:\n{}".format(j, td))
    try:
        col3 = row.find_all('td')[2]
    except IndexError as e:
        print("ERROR on Row {}: {}".format(i, e))
        break
```

Output:

```
Row 0:

 Cell 0:
<td style="width:730px;"><script async="" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script><!-- Top-Banner 728x90, Erstellt 25.12.09 --><ins class="adsbygoogle" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7193398479241689" data-ad-slot="6570665833" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"></ins><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script></td>

 Cell 1:
<td class="logotd"><a href="/oneworld/first.shtml"><img alt="Nations Online Logo" class="displayed" height="60" src="/buttons/OWNO_logo06-60.png" width="60"/>    </a><br><b>One World<br>Nations Online</br></b></br></td>

ERROR on Row 0: list index out of range
```

Perhaps there are some `<td>` elements in the page you're scraping that you want to skip?

**UPDATE**
Here's one way to narrow down the scraped output you're getting.  It looks like the cells you're interested in all are members of the class `border1`.  You can filter for rows that contain cells with this class:

```
for row in rows:
    target_row = row.find_all('td', class_="border1")
    if len(target_row) == 3:
        city, country, code = [td.text for td in target_row]
        print("City: {}, Country: {}, Code: {}".format(city, country, code))
```

Output:

```
City: Aarhus, Country: Denmark, Code: AAR
City: Abadan, Country: Iran, Code: ABD
City: Abeche, Country: Chad, Code: AEH
...
City: Zinder, Country: Niger, Code: ZND
City: Zouerate, Country: Mauritania, Code: OUZ
City: Zurich (Zürich) - Kloten, Country: Switzerland, Code: ZRH
```

Comment: well I am not scraping every table nor every row. I only scrape every 3rd table and then every row except the first. Each row has three data points, city, country and code. I am trying to collect all three. Looking at the table every row has a value in all 3, am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like it - the output I posted is straight from your code, just with debug statements added. Those cell contents are definitely not city/country/code data.

Comment: See my updated answer - I've showed one way to narrow down to the data you're interested in.  In general, use BeautifulSoup attribute filtering (class, name, id, etc) along with element tag names (td, tr, etc) to get exactly what you want.